# Requests issue decoding gzip

Tags: python-2.7, https, gzip, python-requests

I'm trying to pull a large number of text files from a website using the requests package where some of the files are available outright as text and others are compressed text files.

```
tmpHtml = 'https://website.com/csv/pwr/someData.dat.gz'
tmpReq = requests.get(tmpHtml, proxies = proxy_w_auth, auth = (usr, pw))
```

When I pull the uncompressed files, everything works well however when I pull one of the compressed files I get lots of the following:

```
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\xe5\xc6\xd9A\x00\x03someData.dat\x00\xa5\x9d\xcbn\x1c\xb9\x19\x85\xf7\x01\xf2\x0e\xfd\x00Q\xa9X,^j\xa9\xc8\x9a\xb1\x9dX\x16dM\x12/\r\x8c\x0712\x19\x0f\xb2\t\x02\xf4\xc3\xa7\xba\xeeM\x9e\x9f<\xa46s\x93\xf1\r\x8b\xfd\x7fl\x9e\xe2E/\xcfwo\x1eNo\xee^\x1e\xceo\x7f\xfa\xf3\xf9\xe9\xf9\xe3\x9b\x9f\xee_\xce\x9f^\x9e\xdf=\x9d\xef?>\xbe<\xdf\x8d\xff\xba\xfe\xc3\xe9\xe5\xf3\xd3\xc3\xf4\xc3\xbf\x8c\x7f{xy\xf9\xeb\xc3\x87\x87\xc7\x97\xd3\xd3\xf3\xbb\xfb\x87\xf3\xe3\xc3\xcb\xe9\xfe\xed\xdd\xe3\x8f\x0f\xe7\x87\x7f<\xbd{\xbe{y\xf7\xf1qb\xff\xf1\x0f\xeaV\xdfvmk\xce\xf7\xdf~;\xff\xf0\xed\xb7\xd3\xa7\xff~\xf9\xfd\xe6\xe9\xeb\x97\x7f\xfd\xe9\xf4\xc3\xd3\xe9\x97\xef\xff9]\x10\xeaV-\x7f\xec\xdd\xe3\xf9\x87\xf3\xb9W\x8d\xf6\xe7\x1b\xd3\xf4n\xfc\x99\x9e\x7fH\xd3\xba\x90f\x1ak\xce7\xbaQ\xe3\x8f:_\x06\xd31ldu\xe3_tq\xc3z\x91\xd5\xdfvC\x19\xcb\x84,\xdd\xb8\x11\xa6\x9a\xce\x8c?+m\x99\ri\xf6\xc2\xb9i\xc7\xa6\xd9[\xdd\x96\xc1\\\x003vn\xda\xf8\x83\xd2\xa7\xf4\x12\xca\x17?\xe2\x10u\xd8\xe5\xf9\xc6\xa7\x1c\x8a\x1fP\xb5
```

I can see the file name in the beginning of the string that is returned but I'm not sure how I can actually extract the content. According to the requests documentation, it should automatically be decompressing gz files?

http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/community/faq/

The response object looks like it has gzip in the headers as well:

{'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/2.7.10 Windows/7'}

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes web clients request that the server compress a file before sending it.  Not `.gz` files, mind you, since you wouldn't compress something twice.  This cuts down the file size, especially for large text files.  The client then decompresses it automatically before displaying it to the user.  This is what the requests docs in your question describe.  You do not have to worry about this for your use-case.

To decompress a gzipped file, you have to either decompress it in memory using [gzip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) (part of the standard lib) or write it to disk in `'wb'` mode and use the `gzip` utility.